# Join entre dos tablas con django

Tags: django

Estoy intentando hacer un join entre dos tablas de mi base de datos.
Tengo mi modelo llamado parámetro y mi modelo llamado vigencia, este último tiene un atributo que es clave foránea de parámetro.
Necesito listar todos los parámetros y para cada uno de ellos el valor y fecha de la mayor vigencia. Lo que no tengo claro como hacer ese el join entre estos dos modelos para quedarme por cada parámetro su registro del modelo vigencia con mayor fecha

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El join en Django se puede hacer accediendo como atributo, por ejemplo (suponiendo que la clave foránea en el modelo Vigencia se llama "parametro":

```
vigencias = Vigencia.objects.all() # Obtengo todas las vigencias
for vig in vigencias:
    print(vig.parametro) # Imprime el objeto parametro
    print(vig.parametro.descripcion) # Suponiendo que el modelo Parametro tiene un atributo descripcion
```

Una optimización que se puede hacer es usar el `select_related()` (si es que estás seguro que más adelante vas a utilizar la clave foránea), la primera línea quedaría así:

```
vigencias = Vigencia.objects.all().select_related('parametro') # Obtengo todas las vigencias, y los parametros en la misma consulta.
```

De esta forma no va a consultar a la base de datos cada vez que se quiera obtener un parámetro de una Vigencia.

De la misma forma se puede acceder a los atributos en un template:

```
<ul>
    {% for vig in vigencias %}
        <li>{{vig.parametro.descripcion}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Por otro lado, si tenés múltiples modelos conectados también se puede hacer un filtrado en un join, por ejemplo suponiendo que estan los 3 modelos:

```
class Modelo1(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Modelo2(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mod1 = models.ForeignKey(Modelo1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Modelo3(models.Model):
    altura = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mod2 = models.ForeignKey(Modelo2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Se puede realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
mod3 = Modelo3.objects.filter(mod2__mod1__nombre = "Rodrigo") # Hace un join de las 3 tablas y deja solo los que tiene un nombre igual a "Rodrigo"
```

Para el caso de querer obtener la vigencia de fecha mayor, siendo dicha fecha menor igual a hoy sería:

```
vigenciaMasReciente = Vigencia.objects.filter(fecha__lte = date.today()).select_related('parametro').order_by('-fecha')[0] # Primero filtro por fecha menor igual a hoy, despues ordeno de forma decreciente y por ultimo obtengo el primer elemento de ese QuerySet retornado
```

[Acá](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) te dejo para leer sobre el select_related().

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias Genarito, para quedarme solo con la vigencia de mayor fecha pero que sea menor o igual al día actual es correcto si mi query queda de esta manera ? vigencias = vigencia.objects.filter(fecha__lte= date.today())select_related('parametro').order_by('-id')[0]

Comment: De nada! Todo lo que había escrito era de forma ejemplar para que te des una idea de como funcionan las cosas. Ahí edité la respuesta para el caso específico que me describís, obviamente vas a tener que adaptar el código cambiando el nombre de los atributos y de los modelos. Saludos!

Comment: Recién veo tu comentario! Solo deberías cambiar ese `order_by('-id')` por el que te marqué en la respuesta asi ordenas por fecha y no por id. Saludos!

Comment: De esta forma me quedo solo con una vigencia si no entiendo mal y no la de un parametero en particular. Yo necesito quedarme con la vigencia más nueva (siempre menor o igual a hoy ) pero de cada uno de mis parámetros.

Comment: Entonces sacale ese [0] así te retorna todas las que son con fecha menor o igual a hoy ordenadas por fecha

Comment: Excelente, lo pruebo y te comento como me fue. Gracias!

Comment: Buenisimo! Si lo que quieres es obtener los parametros, y a partir de ahi las vigencias de cada uno te recomiendo buscar los `atributos property`, que ya serían muy extensos para incluir en esta pregunta ya que solo iba dedicada al join, pero que son MUY útiles

Comment: estuve probando lo que me comentaste y de esta forma obtengo todas las vigencias por parámetro que cumplen con la condición de la fecha. El problema aquí esta en que al recorrerlas para mostrar en mi grilla de parámetros estoy repitiéndolos ya que para un mismo parámetro puedo tener un montón de vigencias con fecha menor. Lo del Join quedo impecable, pero alguna idea de como puedo hacer para mostrar por parámetro solo una vigencia (la mayor)? Voy a leer sobre los atributos property como me comentas. Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada colega! Te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta con ese nuevo problema para ver soluciones especificas, ya que es un tema aparte. Si la respuesta resolvió tu problema no olvides marcarla como correcta para dar por cerrada la pregunta